# Plot of a sinusoidal function (with certain points emphasized)

Tags: pgfplots

I (now) have the plot of $y = \sin^{2}(x) + \cos(x)$.  I want to plot points at the critical numbers of this function between $-2\pi$ and $2\pi$.  I tried using the command

```
\draw [fill=blue] ({\pi/3},1.25) circle [radius=1.5pt];
```

for example.  I am getting an error.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-8.25,xmax=8.25,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:1.5,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    xtick={-7.33038, -3.14159, -1.0472, 1.0472, 3.14159, 7.33038},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptstyle-$}$\scriptstyle\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$, \makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptstyle-$}$\scriptstyle\pi$, \makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptstyle-$}$\scriptstyle\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\scriptstyle\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\scriptstyle\pi$, $\scriptstyle\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ytick={-1, 1.25},
    yticklabels={$\scriptstyle-1$, $\scriptstyle\dfrac{5}{4}$},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-8:-6.283185, dashed] {(sin(deg(x)))^2 + cos(deg(x))} ;
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-6.283185:6.283185] {(sin(deg(x)))^2 + cos(deg(x))}
\addplot[samples=201,domain=6.283185:8, dashed] {(sin(deg(x)))^2 + cos(deg(x))}

\draw [fill=blue] ({-\pi/3},1.25) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=blue] ({\pi/3},1.25) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=blue] ({-pi},-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=blue] (\pi,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] ({-2*\pi},1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] ({2*\pi},1) circle [radius=1.5pt];

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\pi` is a macro for typesetting a Greek character, it is not a variable in `pgfmath` that corresponds to a number close to 3.14. You want `pi`, without the backslash.

Also you need to make sure you add a semi colon after each `\addplot`, and you're missing `\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\noindent \hspace*{\fill}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=4in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-8.25,xmax=8.25,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
    restrict y to domain=-1.5:1.5,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    xtick={-7.33038, -3.14159, -1.0472, 1.0472, 3.14159, 7.33038},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptstyle-$}$\scriptstyle\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$, \makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptstyle-$}$\scriptstyle\pi$, \makebox[0pt][r]{$\scriptstyle-$}$\scriptstyle\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\scriptstyle\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\scriptstyle\pi$, $\scriptstyle\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ytick={-1, 1.25},
    yticklabels={$\scriptstyle-1$, $\scriptstyle\dfrac{5}{4}$},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-8:-6.283185, dashed] {(sin(deg(x)))^2 + cos(deg(x))} ;
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-6.283185:6.283185] {(sin(deg(x)))^2 + cos(deg(x))};
\addplot[samples=201,domain=6.283185:8, dashed] {(sin(deg(x)))^2 + cos(deg(x))};

\draw [fill=blue] ({-pi/3},1.25) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=blue] ({pi/3},1.25) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=blue] ({-pi},-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill=blue] (pi,-1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] ({-2*pi},1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\draw [fill] ({2*pi},1) circle [radius=1.5pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Declaring a function, removing the `\scriptstyle` which doesn't do much (you also have `\tiny`), using a plot to add the circles.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    declare function={f(\x)=(sin(deg(\x)))^2 + cos(deg(\x));},
    width=4in,axis on top,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-8.25,xmax=8.25,
    ymin=-1.5,ymax=1.5,
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny},
    xtick={-7.33038, -3.14159, -1.0472, 1.0472, 3.14159, 7.33038},
    xticklabels={\makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$, \makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$\pi$, \makebox[0pt][r]{$-$}$\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$, $\pi$, $\dfrac{7\pi}{3}$},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ytick={-1, 1.25},
    yticklabels={$-1$, $\dfrac{5}{4}$},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=21,domain=-8:-6.283185, dashed] {f(x)} ;
\addplot[samples=201,domain=-6.283185:6.283185] {f(x)};
\addplot[samples=21,domain=6.283185:8, dashed] {f(x)};

\addplot [blue,draw=none,mark=*] coordinates {
   (-2*pi,{f(-2*pi)})
   (-pi,{f(-pi)})
   (-pi/3,{f(-pi/3)})
   (pi/3,{f(pi/3)})
   (pi,{f(pi)})
   (2*pi,{f(2*pi)})
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]